# In Django have created custom permissions and assigned permissions to group and user but @permission_required fails

Tags: django

I have created a custom permission in my user model, which is in the app users:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    actual_user = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, default=None)
    
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_switch_user", "Switch user"),)
```

I have migrated the permissions in, added the permission to a group, and have assigned the user the permission and the group. When I test to see if the user has the permission it does not.

```
@login_required
def hello(request):

        
    context = {
        "name": request.user.username,
        "actual_user": request.user.actual_user,
        "groups": Group.objects.all(),
        "permissions": request.user.user_permissions.first(),
        "switch_user": request.user.has_perm('users.can_switch_user')}
    return render(request, "testapp/hello.html", context)
```

I have also tried the permission "users.user.can_switch_user'

hello.html looks as follows (base.html just has the HTML, title and body tags with the block for the body content):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
Actual user: {{actual_user}}<br>
Group: {{group}} <br>
Perms: {{permissions}}<br>
Can Switch User {{switch_user}}

{% endblock %}
```

When I display the results via hello.html I get:

```
Hello user1

Actual user: user1
Group: 
Perms: users | user | Switch user
Can Switch User False
```

Why am I not getting the correct permissions?  Do I need to create a check_permissions method in my user model to make this work or am I doing something else incorrectly.

Comment: The name of the app is `users`? Can you show the `hello.html` *template*?

Comment: Yes, the name of the app for the User model is users.  The app that shows the "hello.html" is a different app "testapp" which I created to test (and view) how the user app works with other apps. I've updated the question with the hello.html template.